# Slighty move around/float grouped elements on hover – jquery animation

Tags: jquery, animation

I already searched the web for a plugin or tutorial to achieve a subtile animation effect, without any success so far :(

I'm going to have a world map with differently sized icons on it. These icons will be arranged in cloud like groups, I think I'll just float the items of one group within a fixed container.

To make it more organic I'd like to add a hover effect, so that the items of one group react on mouseover, slightly moving or floating around as if they were swimming in a bowl and the mouse slightly moves the water around.

Could this be done just with jquery animate()? I'm not sure if it would end in a smooth and 'organic' animation, affecting the whole group when they're just positioned via css floats.

Maybe anybody did something like this before or could point me to an example?

I would really appreciate any help!
Thank u.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using CSS3 keyframe animations.

For example:

```
// define keyframe animation. 
// All it really does is translateY (vertically) from 0 at the start, to 4px at 50% of the duration, then back to 0

@keyframes floating {
    0% {
        transform: translateY(0%);  
    }
    50% {
        transform: translateY(4px); 
    }   
    100% {
        transform: translateY(0%);
    }           
}

// Now apply the animation to an element on :hover
span:hover {
    animation-name: floating;  // the name of animation, assigned above
    animation-duration: 1.5s;  // how long should it take to go from 0 to 100%
    animation-iteration-count: infinite; // how many times it should repeat
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out; // making it smoother due to easing
}
```

You need to add vendor prefixes to make it work in actual browsers, bu here's an example working in Webkit (Chrome, Safari): http://jsfiddle.net/spQET/

Comment: tahnk u pawel, I was hoping to find a js solution because I'd like to support older browsers too. but this really is a nice start!

Comment: Any chances to ease-out the transition on mouseout? It always ends very abrupt, adding transition-timing-function:ease-in-out; doesn't seem to work, also with vendor prefix

Comment: JS solution could work in older browsers, but older browsers are less efficient, possibly installed on slower computers, so it could be a bit of an overkill for them. It's messy, but doable: http://jsfiddle.net/spQET/2/

Comment: yes, you're right. I'll just do it with css3 and don't support other browsers, js would be to much for this little effect. okay, I got it working in css as desired: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alani/jKF8e/) :-) Thanks again!